# Why is InternalViewResolver unable to find jsp file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

This is my App Controller

```java
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public UserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String getHomePage() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getLoginPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userCredentials", new UserCredentials());
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getRegisterPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registered", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView successfullyRegistered(User user) {
        getUserService().registerUser(user);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loggedIn", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView successfullyLoggedIn(UserCredentials userCredential) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        User user = getUserService().validateUserCredential(userCredential.getUserName(), userCredential.getPassword());
        if (user != null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
            return modelAndView;
        } else {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("notFound");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

This is my `InternalViewResolver`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.xyz.login"
})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        //  resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Everytime I run the code, I get HTTP 404 Not Found error. It says:

> Type Status Report
>
> Message JSP file [/LoginSpringMvcHib/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] not found

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
I want to return the home page when the app runs.

Comment: Do you have home.jsp file inside /views?

Comment: Yes, I do have!

Comment: Can you add your directory structure?

Comment: You have specified @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.xyz.login"
}) Can you check your controllers are under login package

Comment: yes, they are in the login package.

Comment: Have you defined SpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer?